# Circuit - solve Kirchhoff's laws with determinant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, voltage

Here is an exercise from my textbook.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgGCH.png)

At first I solve it by using Kirchhoff's laws directly and using complex impendance:
$$U_{in}=\frac{1}{Cs}(i_1-i_2)+i_1R_1$$
$$0=R_2i_2+\frac{1}{Cs}i_2+\frac{1}{Cs}(i_2-i_1)$$

By solving above equations, both $I_1$ and $I_2$ become function of $U_{in}$. Then I sub them into $U_o=i_1R_1+\frac{1}{Cs}i_2$ to get the relationship between $U_o$ and $U_{in}$. This method works and lead to the answer provided in the book.

However I found a solution looks quite different in solution manual with determinant:

Let,

$$\Delta=\begin{vmatrix}
G_2+Cs & -Cs & -G_2\\
-Cs & G_1 + 2Cs & -Cs \\
-G_2 & -Cs & Cs + G_2
\end{vmatrix}$$

then,

$$V_j=\dfrac {\Delta_{1j}} \Delta I_1~~~~~~or~~~~~~
\dfrac {V_3}{V_1}=\dfrac{\Delta_{13}I_1/\Delta}{\Delta_{11}I_1/\Delta}$$

Therefore the transfer function is

$$\dfrac {V_3}{V_1}=\dfrac{\Delta_{13}}{\Delta_{11}}=\dfrac{\begin{vmatrix}-Cs & 2Cs+G_1\\-G_2 & -Cs\end{vmatrix}}
{\begin{vmatrix}2Cs+G_1 & -Cs\\-Cs & Cs+G_2\end{vmatrix}}$$

$$=\dfrac{C^2 R_1 R_2 s^2+ 2CR_1 s+1}{C^2 R_1 R_2 s^2+(2R_1+R_2)Cs+1}$$

So far I am quite confused on what does the first determinant stands for and could this determinant be written down directly without any draft? (If so, I think it will be faster and easier to solve problems like this and I really want to learn about it.) Also, why do we need to use the Minor of that determinant?

Comment: I know the technique for getting the determinant of a circuit by inspection of the circuit. But I am a little confused on the terms shown ($C_S$, $G_1$, and $G_2$).

Comment: @BobD, isn't it $Cs$ or, better, $sC$ where $s$ is the complex frequency $s = \sigma + j\omega$ rather than $C_S$?.  Also, aren't the $G_i$ the conductances of the resistors?

Comment: @AaronStevens From my understanding, Cramer's Rule does not erase both col and row (Minor), but replace one col, to solve equations. And that's why I doubt it is just Cramer's Rule.

Comment: Why is $s$ both a variable and a subscript?

Comment: @Farcher Right... I'm asking why it's a subscript in the question. Edit: The OP didn't do it. I guess I can edit it to be correct.

Comment: @Farcher before my edit there was $C_s$ everywhere there should have been a $Cs$ in the solutions in question. (Look at version 3)

Comment: this might be a good question for the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added some theory before the recipe.

$s= \ j \omega$ where $\omega$ ids the angular frequency and $G$ is the conductance of a resistor of resistance $R$ with $G= \dfrac 1R$

There are three Kirchhoff's current law equations which can be set up for each of the nodes **1**, **2** and **3**.

[image]

For node **1** $(V_1-V_2)sC +(V_3-V_1) G_2 + I_1=0$ where $I_1$ is the current entering the network at node **1** from $+V_{\rm in}$.

Rearranging this equation gives $I_1=(G_2+sC) V_1-sCV_2-G_2V_3$

Repeating the process at nodes **2** and **3** gives $I_2 = -sCV_1+(G_1+2sC)V_2-sCV_3$ and $I_3= -G_2V_1 -sCV_2+(sC+G_2)V_3$

So the admittance matrix for this network is $\mathbf Y=\begin{bmatrix}
G2+sC & -sC & -G_2 \\
-sC & G_1 + 2sC & -sC \\
-G_2 & -sC & sC+G_2\\
\end{bmatrix}$ 
and the matrix equation which links the currents $\mathbf I=\begin{bmatrix}
I_1 \\
I_2 \\
I_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$  and the voltages $\mathbf V=\begin{bmatrix}
V_1 \\
V_2 \\
V_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$  is $\mathbf I = \mathbf Y \,\mathbf V$

Here is the (cookery book) recipe for producing the admittance matrix.

You are dealing with admittances and four nodes which I have labelled **0**, **1**, **2** and **3** and three nodal voltages $V_1,\,V_2$ and $V_3$ which are relative to the reference node **0** which is at a potential of zero.

For element **11** you see that there are two circuit components, resistor $R_2$ and left-hand capacitor $C$,  connected to node **1**.
You add the two admittances to give $G_2 + sC$ and this is the value of element **11** of matrix $\Delta$.

For element **22** you see that there are three circuit components connected to node **2** and you add their admittances which produces $G_1+2sC$.

Finally element **33** have a value of $G_2+sC$.

Now you need to look at components which are common to two nodes to find elements $Y_{\rm ij}$ with $i\ne j$.
The left hand capacitor is common to node **1** and node **2** so the entry for element **12** and **21** is minus the admittance of the component which is $-sC$ in this case.
Elements **23** and **32** are also equal to $-sC$.
Elements **13** and **31** are equal to $-G_2$.

You have thus populated all the elements of the matrix $\mathbf Y$.

To finish off the problem [Cramer's rule](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Precalculus/Book%3A_Precalculus_(OpenStax)/09%3A_Systems_of_Equations_and_Inequalities/9.8%3A_Solving_Systems_with_Cramer%27s_Rule) is used.

---

@PageDavid has provide a reference, [Nodal Admittance Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_admittance_matrix).

Comment: It works like a magic. But what's mathematical theory behind this?

Comment: Things are clear for me, and I'd like to attach [Nodal admittance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_admittance_matrix) here as a reference.

Comment: But why can you express all of the voltages in terms of $I_1$? Also won't Cramer's rule give you $V_j=$ ratio of two $3\times 3$ determinants?

Comment: @AaronStevens In this example there is only one **source** of current $I_1$ on the input side and $I_2=I_3=0$. If you look at what the OP wrote you will see that after Cramer's rule has been applied for $V_1$ and $V_3$, finding their ratio results in a lot of cancellation of terms.

Comment: Ah ok. @PageDavid I guess I should have pushed my initial intuition of Cramer's rule farther (I deleted my initial comment of it).

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, $\Delta$ is the determinant of the nodal admittance matrix $\mathbb{Y}$.  It's also clear that $\mathbf{V}$ is the vector of node voltages. What wasn't clear to me is that $\mathbf{I}$ is the vector of *injected* currents rather than the currents the OP has drawn in red.

That is, $I_1$ is the (phasor) current injected to node 1, i.e., the current into the input port of the network.

Since node 2 (the junction of the two capacitors and $R_1$) is an internal node, the current $I_2$ injected is zero.

Assuming the output port is terminated with an open circuit, the current $I_3$ injected is also zero.

Thus, the only independent variable is $I_1$.

Solving for $\mathbf{V}$ yields

$$\mathbf{V} = \mathbb{Y}^{-1}\mathbf{I} = \frac{\mathbb{C}^T}{\Delta}\mathbf{I}$$

where $\mathbb{C}$ is the [cofactor matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Inverse_of_a_matrix).  Since $I_2 = I_3 = 0$, it follows that

$$V_j = \frac{C_{1j}}{\Delta}I_1$$